# Wordpress adding my home URL to all external links

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a strange issue on my blog. When I add an external link, such as https://www.facebook.com, using the anchor code as below, Wordpress automatically adds my website's URL to the front of the external URL.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com>Facebook</a>
```

In live site, the above code becomes

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/"https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Could anyone check this and help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any weird plugin or scripts related to url?
It need to review your theme files first to find the cause.

Comment: Hi yes. I just found out, it's happening on the Siteorigin Editor only. On the normal WP editor, it works just fine.